# Setting index.max_terms_count has no effect?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm experimenting with index.max_terms_count. I've tried executing a terms query with over 65 536 terms in it, and I was surprised to see it actually gets executed, because I read the warning [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html):

> Executing a Terms Query request with a lot of terms can be quite slow, as each additional term demands extra processing and memory. To safeguard against this, the maximum number of terms that can be used in a Terms Query both directly or through lookup has been limited to  `65536` . This default maximum can be changed for a particular index with the index setting  `index.max_terms_count` .

To test it further, I've tried setting index.max_terms_count to 2 or 3, and it still doesn't work the way I expect it to work. Can you please help me understand what am I doing (or understanding) wrong?

Steps:

1. Run ES using Docker:

   1.1.docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.0

   1.2. docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.0
2. Index document:
   curl -X POST http://localhost:9200/twitter/_doc/1 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
       "user" : "kimchy",
       "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
       "message" : "trying out Elasticsearch",
       "tags": ["foo", "bar", "sun", "clouds"]
   }'
3. Change settings:
   curl -X PUT http://localhost:9200/twitter/_settings  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -d '{
       "index" : {
           "max_terms_count" : 2
       }
   }'
4. Verify settings are applied:
   `curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/twitter/_settings`
5. Perform a search:
   curl -X POST 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
       "query": {
           "terms" : { "tags" : ["sun", "cloudy", "yo", "hi", "hello"]}
       }
   }'

Answer (score 1):

After the ElasticSearch Version 7.0 the default value for `index.max_terms_count` is `65536`, if you provide additional inputs to the terms command more than 65536 with the default `max_terms_count` setting. i.e, for instance, `65537`, it will produce the below exception message

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "query_shard_exception",
        "reason" : "failed to create query: The number of terms [65537] used in the Terms Query request has exceeded the allowed maximum of [65536]. This maximum can be set by changing the [index.max_terms_count] index level setting.",
        "index" : "my_index",
        "index_uuid" : "iJMNOR7znSsmODsG4uArTvQ"
      },
      ....
    ....
    ...
}
```

Elastic search provides a way to increase max_terms_count up to 2147483647. I have tried to set till 2147483647 for testing purposes and it worked perfectly

```
PUT /my-index/_settings
{
    "index" : {
        "max_terms_count" :  2147483647  
     }
}
```

but failed when I started to increase the value to  `2147483648`

```
PUT /my-index/_settings
{
    "index" : {
        "max_terms_count" :  2147483648  
     }
}



{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Failed to parse value [2147483648] for setting [index.max_terms_count]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "Failed to parse value [2147483648] for setting [index.max_terms_count]",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "number_format_exception",
      "reason" : "For input string: \"2147483648\""
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Hence, the max_terms_count does play a role during the query and your index.max_terms_count has effect based on your configuration(with or without default)